# How do you change the mouse pointer style in A-Frame

Tags: mouse, aframe

I don't want the default drag hand. I just want the normal mouse pointer and CSS isn't doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override CSS:

```
.a-canvas.a-grab-cursor:hover{cursor:default !important}.a-canvas.a-grab-cursor:active,.a-grabbing{cursor:default !important}
```

Comment: For some reason, your solution stopped working in a-frame versions above 1.0.0. Is there an alternative, for the most recent version (1.0.4)?