# Aframe change mouse cursor for different elements

Tags: aframe

In Aframe I'm trying to change the mouse cursor for different elements, i.e. to show resize handle when something can be resized.

I've seen this

[How do you change the mouse pointer style in A-Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817522/how-do-you-change-the-mouse-pointer-style-in-a-frame)

And have tried giving entities a class attribute i.e. `class: 'hotspot'`

and adding something like

```
.a-canvas.hotspot.a-grab-cursor:hover{cursor: e-resize !important}
```

But to no avail

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?