# how to Hide default hand cursor in A-Frame for specific entity or How to apply css cursor property "not -allowed"

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have many entities like this and what I want is that when we take mouse over this entity it should be disabled and show a red circle ban icon over it I tried using CSS cursor property  but its not working.

```html
<a-entity
                data-disabled="true"
                data-icon="right"
                data-icon-position="1.16 0 .1"
                data-icon-rotation="0 0 0"
                navigate-to-scene="placeholder"
                rotation="0 -10 0"
                template="src: #main"></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to change a cursor is by overriding the CSS. I don't know how to make it respond to a specific element and not just every hoverable element. But also to check for something like "hovering" you need to have raycaster from your cursor
`<a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .cursor-listener"></a-entity>` Notice that the raycaster responds to specific objects. In this case it'a a class **.cursor-listener**

Example below.

I will link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817522/how-do-you-change-the-mouse-pointer-style-in-a-frame)

```js
function enteredElement() {
  console.log("element hovered");
}

function leavedElement() {
  console.log("element leaved");
}
}
```

```css
.a-canvas.a-grab-cursor:hover{
  cursor:grab !important
}

.a-canvas.a-grab-cursor:active,.a-grabbing{
  cursor:grabbing !important
}

.a-canvas.a-grab-cursor.a-mouse-cursor-hover{
  cursor:crosshair !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene id="scene">
    <a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .cursor-listener"></a-entity>
    
    <a-plane
        position="0 1.6 -1"
        height="0.5"
        width="1.5"
        color="red"
        class="cursor-listener"
        id="element"
        onMouseEnter="enteredElement()"
        onMouseLeave="leavedElement()"
      ></a-plane>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```